# How to create application scope for nunit for ASP.NET Core 3.1 project

Tags: nunit, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm new to unit testing and I think I need to get the application scope of my ASP.NET Core 3.1 web so that I can get some scoped services to use in testing.

Question: how do I get the app object so that I can get the scope?

The error I'm seeing is

> Cannot resolve scoped service 'className' from root provider.

From the Google searches, I think I see that the problem is that `className` is created in the application's `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` with `services.AddScoped<className>()`.

I believe the problem is that Nunit doesn't run in the same scope(?) as the application being tested (not sure).

At any rate, how do I get the app in the nunit test framework?

TIA,

Owen

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

```
IWebhostBuilder builder = Project.Program.CreateTestHostBuilder(new string[] {});
IServiceProvider _serivces = builder.Build.Services();

IServiceScope scope = _services.CreateScope();
className classVar = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<className>();
```

So now I have a scope and access to the ServiceProvider to get the instances of the injected services.

I still do not know how to get the app instance (or, the real question is: how do I inject a DIFFERENT version of a class for testing?).

Thanks,

Owen